# Mixup of multiple plots in same X axis

Tags: r, plot, plotly

I have two plots in my graph. One is group of some indicators.
Second is other group of indicators.

If they are plotted individually the grouping is proper. If they are plotted in single graph sharing the x axis, graphs groupings are showing improperly,

### Section 1 should be (v_plot_sec1)
candlestick
ema_8
bbands

Section 2 should be (v_plot_sec2)
MACD
MACD_signal
RSI
VOLUME

While output in v_plot_fnl is mixed up

Can the proper grouping be generated...

```
library(quantmod)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(plotly)
get_data <- function(symbols = c("AAPL", "MSFT", "META", "ORCL",
                                 "TSLA", "GOOG")) {
    syms <- getSymbols(symbols, from = "2020/01/01", 
                       to = Sys.Date(), periodicity = "daily")
    map_dfr(syms, function(sym) {
        raw_data <- get(sym)
        raw_data %>%
            as_tibble() %>% 
            set_names(c("OPEN", "HIGH", "LOW", "CLOSE", "VOLUME", "ADJUSTED")) %>% 
            mutate(SYMBOL = sym,
                   DATE = index(raw_data)) %>% 
            select(SYMBOL, DATE, OPEN, HIGH, LOW, CLOSE, VOLUME, ADJUSTED)
    })
}

if (!exists("df_all")) {
    df_all <- get_data()
}

p_from_date = Sys.Date() -180
p_to_date   = Sys.Date()
p_isin = 'AAPL'

dt_tst <- as.data.table(df_all[df_all$SYMBOL == 'AAPL',])
dt_tst$inc_dec <- sign(dt_tst$CLOSE-dt_tst$OPEN)

dt_tst[dt_tst$inc_dec ==0, ]$inc_dec = 1
dt_tst$Color = ''
dt_tst[inc_dec==1,]$Color  = '#2F6346'# '#00ff00'
dt_tst[inc_dec== -1,]$Color = '#FF4136' #'#ff0000'
# t line data
dt_tmp_ema8 <- as.data.table(EMA(dt_tst[,CLOSE], n = 8))
names(dt_tmp_ema8) <- 'ema_8'
dt_tst <- cbind(dt_tst, dt_tmp_ema8)                             
#  #--Processing BBANDS
dt_tmp_bbands <-  as.data.table(BBands(dt_tst[,CLOSE]))
names(dt_tmp_bbands) <- paste0('bbands_',names(dt_tmp_bbands)) 
dt_tst <- cbind(dt_tst,dt_tmp_bbands)
#----On Balance Volume
dt_tmp_obv        <-  as.data.table(OBV(dt_tst[,CLOSE], dt_tst[,VOLUME]))
names(dt_tmp_obv) <- 'obv'
dt_tst  <- cbind(dt_tst,dt_tmp_obv)
#----StochWPR
dt_tmp_wpr       <- as.data.table(sprintf(WPR(dt_tst[,c(HIGH,LOW,CLOSE)]),fmt = '%#.3f'))
#---- Average Directional Index
dt_tmp_adx       <- as.data.table(ADX(dt_tst[,.(HIGH,LOW,CLOSE)]))
dt_tst <- cbind(dt_tst,dt_tmp_adx)
#-----RSI
dt_tmp_RSI      <- as.data.table(RSI(dt_tst[,.(CLOSE)]))
names(dt_tmp_RSI) = 'RSI'
dt_tst <- cbind(dt_tst,dt_tmp_RSI)
#---- MACD
dt_tmp_macd        <- as.data.table(MACD(dt_tst[,.(CLOSE)], 12, 26,9,maType = 'EMA'))
names(dt_tmp_macd) <- c('macd','macd_signal')
dt_tst   <- cbind(dt_tst,dt_tmp_macd)
#-- Graphing--------------------------------------------------------------------
# Section 1
cndlstick   <- plot_ly(name = 'candlestick' ,data = dt_tst,type='candlestick', x = ~DATE, low=~LOW, high = ~HIGH, open = ~OPEN, close=~CLOSE)
v_plot_sec1 <- add_trace(cndlstick, name = 'ema_8',  data = dt_tst, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines', x= ~DATE, y = ~ema_8, line = list(color = 'black', width = 2))
v_plot_sec1 <- add_trace(v_plot_sec1, name = 'bbands_dn',  data = dt_tst, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines', x= ~DATE, y = ~bbands_dn, line = list(color = 'gray', width = 1))
v_plot_sec1 <- add_trace(v_plot_sec1, name = 'bbands_mavg',  data = dt_tst, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines', x= ~DATE, y = ~bbands_mavg, 
                         line = list(color = 'black', width = 1,linetype =I("dash")  ))
v_plot_sec1 <- add_trace(v_plot_sec1, name = 'bbands_up',  data = dt_tst, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines', x= ~DATE, y = ~bbands_up, line = list(color = 'gray', width = 1))
# Section 2
v_plot_sec2     <- plot_ly(name =  'MACD', data = dt_tst, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines', x=~DATE,y=~macd,line = list(color = 'black', width = 1))
v_plot_sec2     <- add_trace(v_plot_sec2, name =  'MACD_signal', data = dt_tst, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines', x=~DATE,y=~macd_signal,line = list(color = 'red', width = 1))
y2 <- list(tickfont = list(color = "#ff7f0e"),titlefont = list(color = "#ff7f0e"),overlaying = "y",side = "left", anchor="free",    position=0.15,  title = "RSI")
v_plot_sec2 <- v_plot_sec2 %>% add_trace( type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines', x=~dt_tst$DATE,y=~dt_tst$RSI, yaxis = "y2",  line = list(color = 'black', width = 1))

y3 <- list(tickfont = list(color = "#d62728"),titlefont = list(color = "#d62728"),overlaying = "y",side = "right",title = "yaxis3 title")
v_plot_sec2      <- v_plot_sec2%>% add_trace( data = dt_tst, type = 'bar', x=~DATE, y=~VOLUME, yaxis = "y3",marker = list(color = ~toRGB(Color, alpha = 0.5)))

v_plot_sec2 <- v_plot_sec2 %>% layout(title = "multiple y-axes example", yaxis2 = y2, yaxis3 = y3, xaxis = list(title = 'Date'),# domain = c(0.3, 0.7)),
                                      yaxis = list(title="yaxis title", tickfont = list(color = "#1f77b4"),titlefont = list(color = "#1f77b4")) )%>%
    layout(plot_bgcolor='#e5ecf6',xaxis = list(zerolinecolor = '#ffff',zerolinewidth = 2,gridcolor = 'ffff'),yaxis = list(zerolinecolor = '#ffff',zerolinewidth = 2,gridcolor = 'ffff'))

v_plot_fnl      <- subplot(v_plot_sec1,v_plot_sec2,heights = c(0.6,0.3), nrows= 2, shareX = TRUE, titleY = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Updated Request for a Multi-Plot Slider

If you wanted a range slider that controls both plots, you can use the crosstalk library.

First, create shared data.

```
library(crosstalk)
sd = SharedData$new(dt_tst)
```

Then instead of `data = ds_tst` in your plots, change that to `sd`, so the plots are using the shared data object you created.

I copied the plot code, changed the data source, and incremented the versions for the object names (they end in v3, instead of v2).

Then I created the `filter_slider` object.

```
fs <- filter_slider(id = "data-slider",
              "Set the date range for both plots",
              sd,
              ~DATE)
```

Lastly, I put it all together in `bscols`. (Also from `crosstalk`)

bscols(list(fs, sec1_v3, sec2_v3))

[image]

That code (less data creation) altogether.

```
library(plotly)
library(crosstalk)

sd = SharedData$new(dt_tst)

sec1_v3 <- plot_ly(name = 'candlestick',
                   data = sd, type='candlestick',
                   x = ~DATE, low = ~LOW, high = ~HIGH,
                   open = ~OPEN, close = ~CLOSE) %>% 
  add_lines(name = 'ema_8', y = ~ema_8, 
            line = list(color = 'black', width = 2)) %>% 
  add_lines(name = 'bbands_dn', y = ~bbands_dn, 
            line = list(color = 'gray', width = 1)) %>% 
  add_lines(name = 'bbands_mavg', y = ~bbands_mavg, 
            line = list(color = 'black', width = 1, linetype = I("dash"))) %>% 
  add_lines(name = 'bbands_up', y = ~bbands_up, 
            line = list(color = 'gray', width = 1))

sec2_v3 <- plot_ly(name = 'MACD', type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines',
                   data = sd, x = ~DATE, y = ~macd, 
                   line = list(color = 'black', width = 1)) %>% 
  add_lines(name =  'MACD_signal', y = ~macd_signal,
            line = list(color = 'red', width = 1)) %>% 
  add_lines(y = ~RSI, yaxis = "y2", line = list(color = 'black', width = 1)) %>% 
  add_bars(y = ~VOLUME, yaxis = "y3", 
           marker = list(color = ~toRGB(Color, alpha = 0.5))) %>% 
  layout(title = "multiple y-axes example", yaxis2 = y2, yaxis3 = y3, 
         plot_bgcolor='#e5ecf6', 
         xaxis = list(title = 'Date', zerolinecolor = '#ffff',
                      zerolinewidth = 2, gridcolor = 'ffff'), 
         yaxis = list(title="yaxis title", 
                      tickfont = list(color = "#1f77b4"),
                      titlefont = list(color = "#1f77b4"),
                      zerolinecolor = '#ffff',
                      zerolinewidth = 2,gridcolor = 'ffff'))

fs <- filter_slider(id = "data-slider",
              "Set the date range for both plots",
              sd,
              ~DATE)

bscols(list(fs, sec1_v3, sec2_v3))
```

#### Original Answer

Instead of using subplot, which is unlikely to work out in this case, you could use `browsable` from the package `htmltools`.

I went through your plots a bit to see if there was anything amiss. I didn't change anything, but I did remove some redundancies. Yours work, so these changes aren't *needed*.

Your first plot:

```
sec1_v2 <- plot_ly(name = 'candlestick',
                   data = dt_tst, type='candlestick',
                   x = ~DATE, low = ~LOW, high = ~HIGH,
                   open = ~OPEN, close = ~CLOSE) %>% 
  add_lines(name = 'ema_8', y = ~ema_8, 
            line = list(color = 'black', width = 2)) %>% 
  add_lines(name = 'bbands_dn', y = ~bbands_dn, 
            line = list(color = 'gray', width = 1)) %>% 
  add_lines(name = 'bbands_mavg', y = ~bbands_mavg, 
            line = list(color = 'black', width = 1, linetype = I("dash"))) %>% 
  add_lines(name = 'bbands_up', y = ~bbands_up, 
            line = list(color = 'gray', width = 1))
```

Your second plot:

```
y2 <- list(tickfont = list(color = "#ff7f0e"),
           titlefont = list(color = "#ff7f0e"),
           overlaying = "y", side = "left", anchor="free", 
           position=0.15, title = "RSI")
y3 <- list(tickfont = list(color = "#d62728"),
           titlefont = list(color = "#d62728"),
           overlaying = "y",side = "right", title = "yaxis3 title")

sec2_v2 <- plot_ly(name = 'MACD', type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines',
                   data = dt_tst, x = ~DATE, y = ~macd, 
                   line = list(color = 'black', width = 1)) %>% 
  add_lines(name =  'MACD_signal', y = ~macd_signal,
            line = list(color = 'red', width = 1)) %>% 
  add_lines(y = ~RSI, yaxis = "y2", line = list(color = 'black', width = 1)) %>% 
  add_bars(y = ~VOLUME, yaxis = "y3", 
           marker = list(color = ~toRGB(Color, alpha = 0.5))) %>% 
  layout(title = "multiple y-axes example", yaxis2 = y2, yaxis3 = y3, 
         plot_bgcolor='#e5ecf6', 
         xaxis = list(title = 'Date', zerolinecolor = '#ffff',
                      zerolinewidth = 2, gridcolor = 'ffff'), 
         yaxis = list(title="yaxis title", 
                      tickfont = list(color = "#1f77b4"),
                      titlefont = list(color = "#1f77b4"),
                      zerolinecolor = '#ffff',
                      zerolinewidth = 2,gridcolor = 'ffff'))
```

Calling them together:

```
browsable(div(div(sec1_v2), div(sec2_v2))) # functions browsable & div from htmltools
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Kat for your solution. Is there a possibility of linking the window scroller with the second plot below? This will help to move across the data in the graph with same period.